# Resources on KNN regression

Tags: regression, references, k-nearest-neighbour

I need to write a revision on some regression methods, between them the K-Nearest Neighbors regression. So far I've found a few papers that apply this regression method, however without detailing them. These papers also don't point to any resource that discusses it deeply, maybe because it's a widespread model?

Can someone point any book or reference that better details this method?

Comment: There are some answers in other threads you can find by [searching our site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=nearest+neighbors+wiki%3Ayes).

Answer (score -4):

You might want to look at Thomas Cover's [book](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/047174882X) on Information Theory. It includes $k$ nearest neighbour methods as well as other techniques. There are twelve chapters including one on mutual entropy which also includes nearest neighbour methods.

Comment: Not only is this answer vague and lacking explanation, a quick search of the second edition on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/Elements-Information-Theory-Telecommunications-Processing/dp/0471241954#reader_0471241954) for "kNN" and "neighbor" shows no mention of kNN.  If you're sure the book does cover kNN, then please provide a brief account of what it says.

Comment: Doctor Huber the OP was looking for an authoritative reference and I cited the best choice.

Comment: As you know, I was responding to your earlier telegraphic post--and you still haven't provided any reasons to support your assertion this is "the best choice": such rationale is what we look for in answers, because it sets this site apart from mere lists of references.  And are you sure this book actually deals with *kNN*?  That's a little more specific than "nearest neighbor methods" generally.  The absence of the abbreviation "kNN" from the book altogether suggests is might be covering something different. I'm not sure, so I haven't downvoted--but others seem more certain.